# Stop event on keyup in mootools doesn't work

Tags: event-handling, mootools, stoppropagation, mootools-events

I'm trying to prevent non-numeric characters being entered in a text field. 
My code validates the characters but doesn't stop it being added to text box.

My code:

```
var isNumberKey = function(e){
    //alert(e.which);
    if (e.which > 31 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
        return false;   
    return true;
}

var isBackSpaceKey = function(e){
    return e.which == 8;
}

var isArrowKey = function(e) {
    return e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40;
}

var inputs = $$('.numberOnly');
inputs.addEvent('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
    if (!isNumberKey(e) && !isBackSpaceKey(e) && !isArrowKey(e)){
        e.stop();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

HTML:

```
<input name="t1" type="text" class="numberOnly" id="t1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `keydown` event instead of the `keyup`. I'd do it like this:

```
var inputs = $$('.numberOnly');
inputs.addEvent('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.code >= 48 && e.code <= 57 ){
        return true;
    }
    e.stop();
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TsAkb/

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

Maybe you'd want to allow the "tab" key ,the "enter" key and the "backspace" too =P

Comment: +1 for keydown, as for testing, this looks kind of reasonable to me: `(e.key && e.key.test(/([\d]|tab|backspace|enter|left|right|up|down)/)) || e.stop();`

Comment: in fact: `(e.key && e.key.test && e.key.test(/([\d]|tab|backspace|delete|enter|left|right|up|down)/)) || e.stop();` - needs an extra check as some num pad keypresses are not normalized to strings by mootools and calling `.test` would be unsafe. can also be `e.key && e.key.length && ... ` or it can get duct typed to string just to be safe.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/TsAkb/2/ -> need to add a check for shift status also and convert e.key to string if it comes as number (num pad does).

Comment: Super! I didn't knew you could have a "paste" event :P